# Error 404 when clearing cache on phone browser with React PWA

Tags: reactjs, progressive-web-apps

I'm new to React and PWA development. I have successfully converted a React application to a PWA. The PWA installs correctly on the phone that I am using, however, when I clear the cache on the browser that I used to install the PWA and then open the PWA I am getting the error 404 - File or directory not found. Has anyone experienced this behavior before?  I'm running the PWA in IIS and I used react (16.13.1).

Comment: Please share some more information about the server/CDN, where is this application loaded from? The more information you share, the better otherwise it's hard to guess what might have gone wrong. Good luck!

Comment: Hi amit, thank you for your reply. I discovered my issue. In React, I'd changed the start url property of my manifest.json file to my subdirectory (/blah for instance). This didn't break on the PC as a PWA but the phone version was trying to go to "https://blah/blah". Which caused the 404.